# Unsupported(??) unicode character in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unicode, character-encoding

I'm fairly new to development and I've been having a real issue with this. I need the keyboard extension in my app to be able to insert this character `ⱱ` (Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER V WITH RIGHT HOOK', `U+2C71`). It doesn't appear to be an issue with Swift itself or Xcode as I can type it directly or use `\u{2C71}`. The problem may be iOS not accepting it as all I get on simulator is a ? inside a square.

I've looked everywhere I could find, searched documentation on encoding and nothing seemed to make much sense to me for this particular case. Seems like it couldn't possibly be this complicated so it's probably just beyond me at the moment. I have no clue if this has anything to do with UTF-8,16,etc... or just that iOS won't take this character full stop.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS default fonts (Helvetica for iOS 8 & San Francisco for iOS 9) simply doesn't seem to have this character.

You should probably find another font supporting the character. @Shoaib suggested one ;)

Comment: That's excellent!!! And so simple... It worked, thank's a lot! Now I wouldn't imagine though that other apps (or the system to be more exact) would be able to recognise that character. So that ability would be confined to my application, right? As I understand only jailbroken iOS devices support other fonts (really hoping that I'm wrong!!)

Comment: No, you are right. iOS doesn't support this character out of the box. This means that only your app will be able to display the char (or other apps using alternative font supporting it), eventually people changing the font through jailbreak tweaks will be able to see it on other apps and the system though as you said.

Answer (score 1):

This issue belongs to font support. You have to find fonts that support your all required characters.
BTW this character is supported in FreeSerif font (http://www.fonts2u.com/free-serif.font).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link to the font, it worked perfectly!!